# Ayuda EMULADOR ANDROID

Tags: android-studio

Actualice mi Android Studio en mi Laptop y PC y tengo este problema: Cada vez que uso el Emulador de Android me sale este mensaje.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos Rodrigo, ahi dice: "Ve a Extended Settings" y le agregas un "Custom path" (ruta personalizada) del ADB. Bienvenido a SOes por cierto, date una vuelta por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla :D

Comment: Tienes q agregar el ADB en las variables de entorno de windows...en otras palabras ve donde se ejecuta el ADB y lo agregas en las variables de entorno de windows...

Comment: Agradezco sus consejos pero no pude solucionar el problema. Así que hice una instalación limpia y pude solucionar el problema. Muchas Gracias. Como ultimo dato esto me paso justamente que el IDE me pidió una Actualización. Nuevamente muchas gracias.